# How to load progress bar in android until response comes from server

Tags: android, progress-bar

Hi In my Application I'm sending one request to server to validate the user,after sending the request I'm storing that value in database and making the status as 1, after some time I'm changing the status to 2 in database.Now my android app should wait till the status becomes 2. For this I'm showing the user in mobile progress bar.But my problem is as soon as I send the request progress bar stops displaying in the mobile.

Here is what I have tried.

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
            progressDialog.setMax(100);
            e1 = edittext.getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            params.put("sendingJSON", composeJSON());
            client.post("http://192.168.43.137/gpstracker/check_user.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                public void onSuccess(String response) {

                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                    try {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                            String general = obj.get("success").toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+general, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {
                    if (statusCode == 404) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

            });
        }

    });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // what ever you want to do with No option.
                    }
                }

        );

        alert.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution in this cases is to work with events. Using events you can notify everywhere that something is happening. In your case, you can send an event when "the status changes to 2 in the database" and dismiss the progress dialog. There is a powerful and easy-to-use library to work with events called eventbus:

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

I hope this helps to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to use an AsynkTask to do it. You can create the progress dialog in the **onPreExecute()** method, do what you are trying to do (post action or database update) in **doInBackground()** and once you have everything you want, in the **onPostExecute()** you can dismiss the dialog and send the result/data, if you need to, to your activity.

```
public class yourAsyncTask extends AsynkTask<Params, Params, Params>
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Charging...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            errorMesaje = "Process cancelled";
            cancel(true);
        }
    });
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Params... params) {
//Do your things here...

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void void) {
    super.onPostExecute(void);
    //Use an interface to call your activity and pass the data, you will have to change the attribute of the method in order to do it.
// Dismiss your dialog when your requests have finished
    pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

I don´t understand what are you trying to do exactly, if you just want to be sure that the post action is completed before the progress bar goes off, this solution will be fine. You can also call in the doInBackground() to your database and update it.

Hope it's clear enough!

Comment: in short I'm sending userid to database and making status as 1,admin can change my status as 2 so when status changes to 2 then the progress bar should dismiss.

Comment: I don't know exactly how long is going to take to the admin to change your status, but if you are able to handle it in the doInBackground() that should be fine. What I mean is that you can check the status until you get your spected value, 2 (using a while loop or a new thread with a delay if it takes more time), do all this in the doInBackgroung method, so you can then dismiss the dialog when your status is 2.

Comment: Have you been able to do it?

Comment: please help me with this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182540/how-to-get-location-either-from-gps-or-network-providers-in-android